# jQuery .click() doesn't trigger function in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html form which runs a javascript function before submitting. The html of the form tag is:

```
<form onsubmit="return sub();" method="post" action="useclick.php">
```

The html of the submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

That all works fine, but I want the user to be able to press enter anywhere and for it to submit the form so I've got this bit of code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#submit').focus().click();
    }
});
```

This does exactly what I want in all browser except IE. In IE, it does click the submit button, and send off the form but it doesn't run the sub() function first. It's the same in IE 8 and 10, which are the only versions I have access to at the moment.

For completeness, the sub() function looks like:

```
function sub(){
    document.getElementsByName('coords')[0].value = JSON.stringify(coordsArray);
    return true;
}
```

I'm fairly new to javascript and very new to jQuery so any help would be very useful.

Comment: Never head of `coords` element. only as an attribute of map `area`.

Comment: Try to trigger the `submit` event of the form instead.

Comment: `coords` is the name of an input: `<input type="hidden" name="coords" />`

Comment: oops, i misread the function name, i thought it's `getElementsByTagName`. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
       if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
        $('#your_form_id').submit();
        return false;
       }
    });
```

In a sense you are programmatically submitting and preventing the subsequent chain of events.

**Update:**
Changed it and made a a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3745/) to demo. Let me know if it works for you.

```
<h2>Form</h2>
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
   First Name:<input type="text" name="Fname" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>
   Last Name:<input type="text" name="Lname" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>

   <p><input id="submit" type="submit" /></p>
</form>
<h2>JSON</h2>
<pre id="result">
</pre>
<script>
            $.fn.serializeObject = function()
            {
                var o = {};
                var a = this.serializeArray();
                $.each(a, function() {
                    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                        if (!o[this.name].push) {
                            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                        }
                        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                    } else {
                        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                    }
                });
                return o;
            };
            $(' input').keypress(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    console.log('Enter pressed');
                    $('#submit').blur();
                    $('#myform').submit();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $(function() {
                $('form').submit(function() {
                    console.log('submitted');
                    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>
```

**Update #2**
Hi, you need to make sure that you bind to the elements you want to listen to. In this case all the elements in the your document. In general to listen to key events those elements should be focusable. In this new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEgJH/8/) the enter press event is attached as mentioned. Make sure that you focus (read: click) anywhere in the document first.
Let me know how it goes.

**Update #3**
Added this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEgJH/10/embedded/result/) to make sure that the body is focused and has tabIndex. Please accept answer if this works for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why but that doesn't seem to do anything. I've taken out the `.click()` line from the example in my post and replaced it with `$('#captchaform').submit();` and `return false;` but nothing happens at all when I press enter now.

Comment: Thanks for your really thorough update, and it looks like the right answer, but for some reason mine still isn't working. Using `$('form').submit();` or `$('#myform').submit()` just isn't causing anything to happen at all.

Comment: Tim, do you want to set up a mockup JSFiddle so you can have a proof of concept on how it can be done?

Comment: Ok, here's a stripped down version of my code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEgJH/5/). I want to be able to press enter when the focus is anywhere in the document but that isn't working. Any ideas why? I've also got my original .click() line in there commented out, and that works fine when you uncomment it.

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Your new JSFiddle doesn't seem to work for me either. Does it work for you? I've tried in Chrome and Firefox but pressing enter still doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Tim, I've added a statement that sets the initial focus on the document's body as well as setting the tabIndex. Remember only items that have tabIndex, implicit or explicit can be focusable. Also, make sure that you open the console windows you you can see the log message indicating that the action has been triggered. Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEgJH/10/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0):

IE is strict on the script type. So ensure to use `type="text/javascript"`.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```